# Route-Model-Binding in Laravel 5 with annotation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have read some articles about routing and annotions.

http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-route-annotations

But since routes.php is removed in Laravel 5 and annotations became the favourite routing part. how can i bind a model to a route using annotation?

Comment: do you mean bindings.php is removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5, route model bindings are stored in the `before` method of the `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` class:

```
public function before(Router $router, UrlGenerator $url)
{
    $router->model('user', 'App\User');
}
```

This gets called before any of the routes are loaded.

Comment: What about doing it like this: create a Middleware for all model bindings and put it into the stack in AppServiceProvider?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I suppose you could also set up individual bindings and put them in the optional stack, then specify them in your route annotations with `* @Middleware("modelBinding")` so that they are a little better documented in your code.